# how to write this expression in one line , codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a piece of code , i want to get the result in on line

```
    $lang = $this->config->item('email');
    echo $lang['support_email'] ; die;
```

when i `var_dump`  `$lang` the result

```
array(11) {
  ["useragent"]=>
  string(11) "CodeIgniter"
  ["mailpath"]=>
  string(17) "/usr/bin/sendmail"
  ["protocol"]=>
  string(4) "mail"
  ["smtp_host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["smtp_user"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp_pass"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp_port"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["system_email"]=>
  string(21) "noreply@elephanti.com"
  ["help_email"]=>
  string(18) "help@elephanti.com"
  ["inquiries_email"]=>
  string(23) "inquiries@elephanti.com"
  ["support_email"]=>
  string(21) "support@elephanti.com"
}
```

i tried

echo `$this->config->item('email')['support_email']`

and

```
echo echo `$this->config->item('email')->support_email
```

please help.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do `echo $this->config->item('email')['support_email']` in PHP 5.4+

Otherwise the best you can do is:

```
$lang=$this->config->item('email');echo $lang['support_email'];exit;
```

Or write a custom function to do it for you.

*But then ask yourself, why must you do this on one line...?*

Answer (score 3):

```
$lang = $this->config->item('email', 'support_email');
```

From the doc:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

> `// Retrieve a config item named site_name contained within the` blog_settings array`
>
> `$site_name = $this->config->item('site_name',`
> `'blog_settings');`

Comment: According to CodeIgniters documentation, that line would actually work. As I don't use CodeIgniter, I didn't know that, but this is the best answer. +1

Comment: @BerryLangerak in fact I have never used CI as well, I just thought they surely have something to achieve what OP wants easier :)

Answer (score 1):

> `echo $this->config->item('email')['support_email']`

This actually works in PHP > 5.4. In older versions, it's not possible to do it in one statement, so you'll have to store the array in a separate local variable. You can create a function that will retrieve a value like so:

```
 <?php
 function array_get( array $array, $index ) {
    return isset( $array[$index] ) ? $array[$index] : false;
 }

 echo array_get( $this->config->item( 'email' ), 'support_email' );
```

But that's useless really. Any particular reason you want to do it in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($lang as $key=>$val)
{
  if($key == "support_email")
  {
    echo $val;
  }
}
```